# phpの開始タグについて

Tags: php

**下記認識で合っているでしょうか？**
・phpの開始タグは、全部で3種類？

---

```
<?php
```

・全バージョンで、常に有効

---

```
<?
```

・「`<?php`」の省略形
・ php.ini で short_open_tag を有効にするか --enable-short-tags オプションつきで PHP を configure した場合でのみ、有効

---

```
<?=
```

・「`<?php echo`」の省略形
・PHP 5.4.0 以降では、常に有効

---

[PHP タグ](http://php.net/manual/ja/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)
[PHP タグの短縮型](http://php.net/manual/ja/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 0):

PHP7より廃止された物も含むなら

http://php-beginner.com/reference/basic/phptag.html

がありますが、　そういうコードを読まないといけない場合の参考程度で良いと思います。

phpのマニュアル http://php.net/manual/ja/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php
にある通りの理解でよろしいかと。